# How to make login page in ngx-admin nebular

Tags: angular, routes

I am new to angular 5. And I know very basic routing.So please help me with this problem.I have downloaded ngx-admin from https://github.com/akveo/nebular and now I want to make login page for it , which will come first when user will hit the url.I tried this but is is not working,this is app-routing.module.ts

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import {
      NbAuthComponent,
      NbLoginComponent,
      NbLogoutComponent,
      NbRegisterComponent,
      NbRequestPasswordComponent,
      NbResetPasswordComponent,
    } from '@nebular/auth';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path : '' , component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
   {
      path: 'auth',
      component: NbAuthComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          component: NbLoginComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'login',
          component: NbLoginComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'register',
           component: NbRegisterComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'logout',
          component: NbLogoutComponent,
       },
        {
          path: 'request-password',
         component: NbRequestPasswordComponent,
        },
        {
         path: 'reset-password',
          component: NbResetPasswordComponent,
       },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

And this is page-routing.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ManageComponent } from './manage/manage.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  // path: '/home',
  path:'',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
  }, {
    path: 'ui-features',
    loadChildren: './ui-features/ui-features.module#UiFeaturesModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'add-booking',
    loadChildren: './add-booking/addbooking.module#AddbookingModule',
  },{
    path: 'components',
    loadChildren: './components/components.module#ComponentsModule',
  }, {
    path: 'maps',
    loadChildren: './maps/maps.module#MapsModule',
  }, {
    path: 'charts',
    loadChildren: './charts/charts.module#ChartsModule',
  }, {
    path: 'editors',
    loadChildren: './editors/editors.module#EditorsModule',
  }, {
    path: 'forms',
    loadChildren: './forms/forms.module#FormsModule',
  }, {
    path: 'tables',
    loadChildren: './tables/tables.module#TablesModule',
  },
  {
  path: 'manage',
  component: ManageComponent,
},
{
path: 'user',
component: UserComponent,
},{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }],
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: any error you receive

Comment: no..I am not getting error but the page is loading , it is not showing any result.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the redirectTo in app-routing.module.ts:
redirectTo: 'auth/login'

Answer (score 0):

## Hey Change it to like this

```
App-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
  {
    path: '',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: NbRegisterComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'logout',
        component: NbLogoutComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'request-password',
        component: NbRequestPasswordComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'reset-password',
        component: NbResetPasswordComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];
```